# calculate increase values by groups (geom_line) in ggplot with an exeption of first x value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set:

```
biceps <- data.frame(hand = c("L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R"),
                     date = c("2023-07-20", "2023-09-20", "2023-10-29", "2023-07-20", "2023-09-20", "2023-10-29"),
                     size_cm = c(36.8, 37.8, 37.9, 37.1, 38.6, 38.85))
```

I want to get increase/gain values per date compared with a previous date with an exeption of the first date (+0) using `after_stat` without additional precalculation:
[image]

All I have is:

```
ggplot(biceps, aes(x = date, y = size_cm, group = hand)) +
  geom_line() +
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential option is to calculate the labels 'conditionally', e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

biceps <- data.frame(hand = c("L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R"),
                     date = c("2023-07-20", "2023-09-20", "2023-10-29", "2023-07-20", "2023-09-20", "2023-10-29"),
                     size_cm = c(36.8, 37.8, 37.9, 37.1, 38.6, 38.85))

ggplot(biceps, aes(x = date, y = size_cm, group = hand)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(date != first(date),
                               ifelse(size_cm - lag(size_cm, default = 0) > 0,
                                      paste0("+", round(size_cm - lag(size_cm, default = 0), 2)),
                                      paste0("-", round(size_cm - lag(size_cm, default = 0), 2))),
                               0)),
            position = position_nudge(y = 0.1)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 18)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It's a shame it's not possible to use `after_stat`, but this is a pretty laconic desicion.

Comment: Thanks; sorry I couldn't think of a way using `after_stat()` but I'm glad you solved your problem.